# IOS Playback syncrhonized audio/video from different sources delivered with proprietary protocol

Tags: ios, audio, video, media-player, media

In our architecture we have a custom protocol to communicate with our server.

When playing video there are two streams sent to the client using our custom protocol - one for audio (AAC) and one for video (h264). Each stream has a pts.

In looking at writing an ios app we haven't been able to find a method to play media unless it originates from a file or a URL - neither of which our system has available.

My question - Is there method to feed audio and video data for synchronized playback without a URL or file?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you need the streams to work?  There are countless numbers of a/v feed methods, and we need more information to be able to find a specific solution.

Comment: The two streams will be played together for synchronized playback.

Comment: The server demuxes a media file into an audio stream and a video stream.

The audio is sent via method A using protocol XYZ.
The video is sent via method B using protocol XYZ.

The client will take audio data extracted from protocol XYZ and feed to some player.

The client will do the same with video data.

Comment: For another example (this is not what I am doing, but the concept is the same):   Consider you have an app that creates h264 frames with PTS in thread A and creates AAC audio with PTS in thread B. How would you synchronize playback in IOS of the generated audio and video?